# create live windows 7 gadget

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I did lot of googling but could not find proper answer.
I want to create gadget for windows 7 which will be showing some live data from database.(will be creating web service)

how should i proceed with this.I created html file which talk with webservice (used jquery )and display data in tabular format.

what else i need to do? how it will get installed on clients machines?how to deploy this? which technology i should use so that it will always shows live updated data.i will be comfortable with net c#.

please please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you know gadgets are deprecated? Windows 8 doesn't support desktop gadgets. I'd argue that you'd create a program in the taskbar instead.

Comment: Gadget packages are in fact ZIP archives, you can pick an existing one, unpack it and reverse engineer your way through it.

Comment: hi,
i created an html file ad accesses webs ervice throught it successfully.

now i want to get logged in user name and send it as parameter to webservice.

while using javascript to access logged in user naem i have to make internet security low wchich is not feasible.

how to get current logged in user name in HTMl page?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456468(v=vs.85).aspx

above link will help u to create ur first gadget.
It basically need a html and a xml file, in a folder named as a foldername.gadget.
this folder is placed in Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets